# AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'connect' Pydle, Asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

Trying to use pydle with asyncio. A few month ago my code works great now I can't get it to run anymore.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
class MyOwnBot(pydle.Client):
     async def on_connect(self):
        await self.join('#new')

iclient = MyOwnBot('testeee', realname='tester')
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(iclient.connect('irc.test.net', 6697, tls=True,tls_verify=False), loop=loop)
```

But I get this error:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(iclient.connect('irc.test.net', 6697, tls=True, tls_verify=False), loop=loop)
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Comment: Why did you make the *whole class* a coroutine? Remove the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator from the class.

Comment: then I get an additional error. line 520, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('A Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required')
TypeError: A Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required. So guess I should keep the coroutine.

Comment: No, you should not. We can fix the next problem you have without it.

Comment: Are you sure the `pydle.Client.connect()` method is an awaitable? Perhaps they take care of their own loop?

Comment: I thought it is because a few weeks back the whole code works. But i had to  switch systems.

Comment: The [documentation suggests otherwise](http://pydle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#a-simple-client).

Comment: Do you got any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pydle` library [takes care of the event loop for you](http://pydle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#asynchronous-functionality). Also, marking a whole class as a coroutine doesn't work; a class is not a unit of work, the methods *on* the class are.

To ensure cross-python-version compatibility, the library includes it's [own `async` handling module](https://github.com/Shizmob/pydle/blob/master/pydle/async.py):

```
import pydle

class MyOwnBot(pydle.Client):
    @pydle.coroutine
    def on_connect(self):
        yield self.join('#new')

iclient = MyOwnBot('testeee', realname='tester')
iclient.connect('irc.test.net', 6697, tls=True, tls_verify=False)
```

The `Client.connect()` method starts the loop (but you can pass one in if you need to use the same loop elsewhere).

Comment: It works so far for me but I would like to build a bridge between discord and IRC. Sadly that won't work https://pastebin.com/8wydF8ar but can't figure out why. Maybe because of the own handling module?

Comment: @Kenny: `iclient.connect()` takes a loop parameter, perhaps share the loop you create?

Comment: Could you give me an example how? Ihm not quite sure how you mean that.

Comment: @Kenny: the [`BasicClient.connect()` method](http://pydle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client.html?highlight=connect#pydle.BasicClient.connect) takes an `eventloop` argument. Add `eventloop=loop` to the `iclient.connect()` call to share the loop.

Comment: self.eventloop.register(self.socket.fileno())
AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute 'register'

Comment: Right, then the library uses their own non-asyncio-compatible loop and won't take any asyncio loops.

Comment: Sorry, I don't.